# TableLayout не помещается текст

Tags: android, xml

Пытаюсь сделать таблицу для расписания, добавил textView'ы, в итоге последний textView попал за экран, каким образом можно сделать перенос?

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:collapseColumns="6"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:shrinkColumns="*">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
        android:transitionGroup="false">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Мат.моделирование"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Инфок. системы и сети"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Системное программирование"
            android:id="@+id/textView4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Инфок. системы и сети"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:singleLine="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Теория алгоритмов"
            android:id="@+id/textView6" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/textView7" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Мат.моделирование"
            android:id="@+id/textView8" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Инфок. системы и сети"
            android:id="@+id/textView9" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Системное программирование"
            android:id="@+id/textView10" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Инфок. системы и сети"
            android:id="@+id/textView11" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Теория алгоритмов"
            android:id="@+id/textView12" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Так это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дайте скриншот.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/RmzXV8gTNlMkAO.png

Comment: Вы можете попробовать, например, настроить вес у элементов `TableRow`

Comment: А каким образом?

Comment: гляньте тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/16903608/5634351

Comment: таким же, как в `LinearLayout`

Comment: нет не вариант, текст накладывается на соседние надписи http://joxi.ru/MAj09WMcKG1Nme.png